# css not loading in fullcalendar when switching to tab

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, bootstrap-tabs

I have a tablist panel and the last tab uses a fullcalendar

And there is such a problem that when switching to the tab, the css of the calendar is not loaded, BUT if I switch to another month in the calendar itself, then the css starts working

My version of the calendar is 5.7.2, for versions 3 I did not observe such a problem, what could be the problem?

```js
var data = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        editable: false,
        contentHeight: 705,
        events: data
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.0.0-beta.1/main.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-TAVtO5mj3yhqvqWq539ELZe1kdI+ggl2XkVNJ7h33EeYK03qTyiKPbTu2DrrsuWlggnvCr3+A29goA7y0aZSFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.2/main.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">
                                Home
                            </button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">
                                Profile
                            </button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="nav-calendar-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-calendar" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-calendar" aria-selected="false">
                                Calendar
                            </button>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-calendar" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-calendar-tab">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your calendar is loading during page load but the css is not applied as the calendar element is hidden that time. You can move your calendar load on tab click and give a small time interval like 500 ms. Try the below code

```
  <script>
   var data = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#nav-calendar-tab").on("click", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    headerToolbar: {
                        left: 'prev',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'next'
                    },
                    editable: false,
                    contentHeight: 705,
                    events: data
                });

                calendar.render();
            }, 500);
           
        });

    });//end of document.ready

   </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works when switching to tab. But if we assume my calendar tab is initially active, then nothing will be displayed. Is it possible to keep your code and make it so that if the tab is initially active, then the content is also displayed?

Answer (score 1):

call your function on `'shown.bs.tab'` your code run after this tab show

```
var data = [];
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('nav-calendar-tab');
$(document).ready(function () {
  calendarEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
   var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'next'
        },
        editable: false,
        contentHeight: 705,
        events: data
      });
      calendar.render();
  })
});//end of document.ready
```

```js
 var data = [];
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('nav-calendar-tab');
$(document).ready(function () {
  calendarEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
   var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'next'
        },
        editable: false,
        contentHeight: 705,
        events: data
      });
      calendar.render();
  })
});//end of document.ready
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.0.0-beta.1/main.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-TAVtO5mj3yhqvqWq539ELZe1kdI+ggl2XkVNJ7h33EeYK03qTyiKPbTu2DrrsuWlggnvCr3+A29goA7y0aZSFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.2/main.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">
                                Home
                            </button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">
                                Profile
                            </button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="nav-calendar-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-calendar" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-calendar" aria-selected="false">
                                Calendar
                            </button>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-calendar" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-calendar-tab">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works when switching to tab. But if we assume my calendar tab is initially active, then nothing will be displayed. Is it possible to keep your code and make it so that if the tab is initially active, then the content is also displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the calendar is (re-)rendered when the tab containing the calendar is shown. This is because the calendar appears to decide on its rendered sized based on the size of its container. This makes sense most of the time, but the problem here is that when the tab is hidden, the container size is 0, which obviously then causes the calendar to compress in the way we can see in your question.

Note that you don't need to re-run the entire calendar configuration code each time the tab is shown, you only need to call `render()`.

Solution:

```js
var data = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'next'
    },
    editable: false,
    contentHeight: 705,
    events: data
  });

  var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]');
  tabButtons.forEach(function(tabEl) {
    tabEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
      if (event.target.innerText == "Calendar") calendar.render();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.0.0-beta.1/main.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-TAVtO5mj3yhqvqWq539ELZe1kdI+ggl2XkVNJ7h33EeYK03qTyiKPbTu2DrrsuWlggnvCr3+A29goA7y0aZSFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.2/main.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">
                                Home
                            </button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">
                                Profile
                            </button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="nav-calendar-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-calendar" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-calendar" aria-selected="false">
                                Calendar
                            </button>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-calendar" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-calendar-tab">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the calendar tab needs to be the first active tab, the best workaround I can find is to set a different tab as active, and then use Javascript to "show" the calendar tab, which will then trigger the "shown" event and render the calendar.

(Just rendering the calendar immediately after declaring it didn't work - I assume because this happened before bootstrap had rendered the tab pane).

Demo:

```js
var data = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'next'
    },
    editable: false,
    contentHeight: 705,
    events: data
  });

  var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]');
  tabButtons.forEach(function(tabEl) {
    tabEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
      if (event.target.innerText == "Calendar") calendar.render();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.0.0-beta.1/main.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-TAVtO5mj3yhqvqWq539ELZe1kdI+ggl2XkVNJ7h33EeYK03qTyiKPbTu2DrrsuWlggnvCr3+A29goA7y0aZSFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.2/main.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">
                                Home
                            </button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">
                                Profile
                            </button>
    <button class="nav-link" id="nav-calendar-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-calendar" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-calendar" aria-selected="false">
                                Calendar
                            </button>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-calendar" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-calendar-tab">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Relevant documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#events

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already asked this question here. But if we assume my calendar tab is initially active, then nothing will be displayed. Is it possible to keep you code and make it so that if the tab is initially active, then the content is also displayed?

Comment: @Hector I've updated the answer to show what you can do in that case.